# $\dim \mathcal{S}_k(\Gamma_0(N))$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, vector-spaces, modular-forms

I'm looking for a formula which gives the dimension of $\mathcal{S}_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ the space of cusp forms of weight $k$ and level $N$. I found the following statement for $k\geq 4$
$$\dim \mathcal{S}_k(\Gamma_0(N))=\frac{k-1}{12}\nu(N)+\left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{4}\right\rfloor-\frac{k-1}{4}\right)\nu_2 (N)+\left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\right\rfloor-\frac{k-1}{3}\right)\nu_3 (N)-\frac{1}{2}\nu_{\infty}(N)$$
but I don't even know what $\nu(N)$, $\nu_2(N)$, $\nu_3(N)$ and $\nu_{\infty}(N)$ are...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Careful statements of the formulae, with all notation defined in full, can be found in any decent textbook on modular forms e.g. Diamond & Shurman, or Stein (the latter is freely available on the web at http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This website is nice !